# jQuery - Some Smart Idea to not repeat the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the code:

```
$(".redd").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".redd").css("background-color");
});
$(".pink").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".pink").css("background-color");
});
$(".purple").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".purple").css("background-color");
});
$(".indigo").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".indigo").css("background-color");
});
$(".cyan").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".cyan").css("background-color");
});
$(".blue").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".blue").css("background-color");
});
$(".yellow").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".yellow").css("background-color");
});
$(".green").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".green").css("background-color");
});
$(".orange").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".orange").css("background-color");
});
$(".black").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".black").css("background-color");
});
```

What does this code do? 
for example $(".redd") is button, and on click it will change the variable 'fillcolor' to the button's background color. 
How to write this code smarter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a common class and use $(this) to get the one that was clicked on

```js
$(".color").click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
    console.log(fillcolor);
});
```

```css
.green {
    background-color: green
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="green color" value="green" />
<input type="button" class="blue color" value="blue" />
```

Comment: but wait xD I don't have any "color" class

Comment: So add it to the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, feel free to add suggestions!

```
var arry = [".redd", ".pink", ...]
for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
{

  $(arry[i]).click(function() {
    fillcolor = $(".purple").css("background-color");
})
}
```